# Need to load function from other domain js in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to load function from other domain js on my current vuejs development can you please help me for that how to load functions and methods from the other domain js and i need to load into my development

Comment: import { InitCaptcha,myLck,CheckOSDataAvailable,CurruntTime,RefreshCaptcha,CheckCaptcha,getAPIData,LeavePage,autosubmitPlugin,PassCaptcha_Details } from "./CaptchaResourceVue.js"

Comment: i have used my local file like above comment can you please help me i want to load js file from other domain

Comment: You can simply download their JS file and put it inside your development environment. Then it will no longer be "other domain" - but your own project code.

Comment: it's mendatory to use the code from other domain uploaded js is it possible to do that @IVOGELOV

Comment: If the code from the other domain is an ES6 module - then you can import like you demonstrated in your comment. IF the code is in ES5 format - you will have to load it like every other script - by using `<script src="other_domain">`